# Linux shell passing column position dynamically

Tags: loops, awk, parameter-passing

question is: how to pass column position (e.g., $2) dynamically through a loop.
Example file temp1

```
a 1 2  
a 2 3  
b 1 1  
b 3 2  
c 1 5   
c 2 6
```

code so far (does not work :-))

```
#!/bin/bash
twopq () {

awk -v c1="$1" -v c2="$2" '{ if ($1==c1 && c2 == 1) {print}}' temp1 > temp2 

}
twopq a $2
twopq b $3
```

Desired output in temp2 from 1st loop (1st col = 'a' and 2nd col = 1)
a 1 2

desired output in temp2 from 2nd loop (1st col= b and 3rd col = 1)
b 1 1

my pb is to pass the "$" through my loop to tell I'm looking for col2 in the first loop and col3 in the second loop

thanks for the help!

Comment: `$1 == c1` works but the 2nd condition `c2 == 1` doesn't make sense to me.  Also, you want to append to the output file then you need `>>`

Comment: Hi Alan - thanks for the comment - the script shown is a simple extract of a larger script (30 cols) where I need to loop over different elements of col1 (the part that works), but at every loop I need to look to a different column

Comment: if the plan is to call this function within a `bash` loop, with each loop calling the function with different args, ypu'll end up scanning the input file once for each pass through the `bash` loop; from a performance perspective it may be better to feed a list of function call args to a single `awk` call which in turn would perform a single pass through the input file ... though if you don't understand this, or you do understand but have problems implementing, then you'll want to ask a new question (ie, don't edit this question to expand the scope to include the parent loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- 1st argument is a value we're looking for in the 1st column of the input file
- 2nd argument is the column number we're looking for that has a value of `1`
- print *all* lines that match the search criteria

Adding a couple lines to demonstrate multiple matches:

```
$ cat temp1
a 1 2
a 2 3
b 1 1
b 3 2
c 1 5
c 2 6
d 1 5                 # new line
d 1 9                 # new line
```

A few tweaks to OP's current code:

```
twopq () { awk -v val="$1" -v colnum="$2" '$1==val && $(colnum)==1' temp1; }
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ twopq a 2
a 1 2

$ twopq b 3
b 1 1

$ twopq d 2
d 1 5
d 1 9
```

**NOTES:**

- once the output is verified OP can update the function as needed to capture the output to `temp2` (eg, `> temp2` to overwrite on each function call; `>> temp2` to append with each function call)
- alternatively, route the output from the function call to the output file (eg, `twopq a 2 > temp2`, `twopq b 3 >> temp2`)

Comment: hiya! - wonderful - simple - I had not tried that $(colnum) and it works - awesome my friend!!

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

twopq () {    
    awk -v c1="$1" '($1==c1) {
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i == 1) {print;exit}
    }' temp1 | tee -a temp2 

}
twopq a 2
twopq b 3
```

### Output

```
a 1 2  
b 1 1
```

Comment: Hi Gilles - merci for the comment - so I get it right, in your option I would start my second variable to  then iterate over it - so the next loop is 3, then 4 ... - right?

Comment: It start from 2th to any number of columns

Comment: very nice Gilles! I'll keep that in mind !

Answer (score 1):

did you tried to use $c2 inside if condition ?

```
awk -v c1="$1" -v c2="$2" '{ if ($1==c1 && $c2 == 1) {print}}' temp1 > temp2
```